# Convert single char into byte C++

Tags: c++, casting, char, byte

How do I convert a single char into byte?

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* The input argv[1] is a number */
    function(byte(argv[1]));
}
function A(Byte b)
{}
```

Is this the right way of conversion?

Comment: You can use `std::stoi` from the `<string>` header to convert the argument to an `int`. The `int` converts implicitly to byte value.

Comment: It seems you are trying to convert `argv[1]` to a byte. `argv[1]` is **not** a single char. It not even a `char`. It's a pointer-to-`char`. Are you trying to convert a (C-style) **string** to a byte?

Comment: Can you show sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand what `argv` is. That's an array of an array of characters, or an array of strings. So if you were to run:

> > Program.exe param1 param2

`argv` would consist be:

```
argv[0]: Drive:\FullPath\Program.exe
argv[1]: param1
argv[2]: param2
```

If you want a specific character, then you would need something like `argv[1][0]` which would give you `p`.

Note that even if you pass a parameter of a single character, it still comes in as a string, and you must access the specific index. You comment says you're passing in a number, so I would suggest using the `atoi` function, and rather than casting it, using `abs` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain clearly. The input argv[1] can only be between 1 to 5. The atoi function works. Thank you!

Comment: `argv` is not an array of array of chars. It's a pointer to pointer to chars.

Comment: Wouldn't `argv[3]` also be null in that scenario? I do believe it would.

Comment: @nabijaczleweli, yes, though not sure why that is releavant.

Comment: @David (a) I was just making sure, and (b) it allows for cleaner(?) argument processing loops. (I've seen horrible things regarding argument processing.)